# Set methods inside Session in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

Let's say I want to set a Session to an object which contains a method:

```
Session.set('coolSession', {
  something: 1,
  anArray: [1,2,'three'],
  aMethod: function() {
    alert('called aMethod!');
    return 1;
  }
})
```

Now if I call `Session.get('coolSession')` I only get:

```
Object {something: 1, anArray: Array[3]}
```

And as you can see my method is gone. :(

Is this by design or is it a bug? I guess there could be some dangers in assigning methods to Sessions, but I'm not quite sure about what they could be?

Comment: Session values are preserved through hot code reload, and I guess this requires them to be serialized in such a way which destroys functions. It's not a bug, since the documentation mentions that you can only store EJSONable values in the Session.

Comment: Ah OK. I guess I'll just have to store a string representation of the method (which is stored in some other object) and the call the method from the string. Or something! Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need to preserve through HCR, you could just write your own reactive store using `Deps.Dependency`.